# How to concatenate text by Group in DAX, EARLIER function not working

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure in DAX to concatenate all CODES that have the same Group ID.

I have tried the CONCATENATEX function mentioned in many other discussion threads but it doesn't seem to function as there appears to be a problem with the function EARLIER which doesn't recognize any value.

This is the initial table:

[image]

The desired output should be as such:

[image]

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
CODES = CONCATENATEX(FILTER(SPN, SPN[Group Registration ID]=EARLIER(SPN[Group Registration ID])), SPN[SPN CODE], "; ")
```

I would appreciate any orientation

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
Codes = --The purpose of this measure is concat the codes associated with the reg. id
IF(
 ISFILTERED('table'[Group Registration ID])=TRUE(),
  CONCATENATEX(VALUES('table'[SPN CODE]), 'table'[SPN CODE], ", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `SELECTEDVALUE` approach. This measure efficiently iterates through each group, avoiding potential issues with EARLIER. Users can customize the table name and delimiter for their specific requirements.

```
Codes = VAR
  CurrentGroupId = SELECTEDVALUE('YourTableName'[Group Registration ID])
RETURN
  CONCATENATEX(
    FILTER('YourTableName', 'YourTableName'[Group Registration ID] = CurrentGroupId),
    'YourTableName'[SPN CODE],
    "; "
  )
```